# Read multiple CSV files and manipulate before combining

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to import multiple CSV files using dplr into one tibble, but would also like to capture the file name of each file as a new field as part of the data import.

Let's say file01.txt has this data

```
F1, F2
A, 1
B, 2
C, 3
```

and file02.txt has this data

```
F1, F2
D, 4
E, 5
F, 6
```

and file03.txt has this data

```
F1, F2
H, 7
I, 8
J, 9
```

I can make a vector with the file names:

```
Fnms <- c("file01.txt", "file02.txt", "file03.txt" )
```

... and read the first file and add the first file name in a new field.

```
tmp <- read_csv(Fnms[1]) 
tmp$Fnm <- Fnms[1]
```

To read the other two files and append their names I tried a loop structure and messy if-else statements:

```
for (i in 2:3){

  tmp <- tmp %>% 
         bind_rows(read_csv(Fnms[i])) %>% 
         mutate(Fnm = ifelse(row_number() > 3 & row_number() <= 6, Fnms[i], Fnm )) %>% 
         mutate(Fnm = ifelse(row_number() > 6 , Fnms[i], Fnm ))
}
```

Which produces this incorrect result (also not sure why the first mutate is not skipped when i=3?)

```
> tmp
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  F1       F2 Fnm       
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>     
1 A         1 File01.txt
2 B         2 File01.txt
3 C         3 File01.txt
4 D         4 File03.txt
5 E         5 File03.txt
6 F         6 File03.txt
7 G         7 File03.txt
8 H         8 File03.txt
9 I         9 File03.txt
```

I have a solution that works in base R using a loop and rbind, but I'm keen to find a dplyr solution as I'm still learning this newer version of the R language!

Comment: A few options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000995/how-can-i-read-multiple-csv-files-into-r-at-once-and-know-which-file-the-data-is

Comment: `read_csv()` can read multiple indentically formatted files and add an identifier, so you can just do `read_csv(Fnms, id = "Fnm")`.

Comment: Ritchie that's the sort of solution I was looking for !

Comment: I have re-opened the question since none of the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000995/how-can-i-read-multiple-csv-files-into-r-at-once-and-know-which-file-the-data-is provide a dplyr solution which is what the question asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asked for a dplyr solution so try this:

```
library(dplyr) # version 1.1.0 or later

File <- c("file01.csv", "file02.csv")
data.frame(File) %>%
  reframe(read.csv(File), .by = File)
```

giving:

```
        File F1 F2
1 file01.csv  A  1
2 file01.csv  B  2
3 file01.csv  C  3
4 file02.csv  D  4
5 file02.csv  E  5
6 file02.csv  F  6
```